# Usar div y funciones que cuando se abra la ventana se muestre solo el desplegable

Tags: javascript, php

Necesito  hacer que cuando hayamos pulsado **Si** le demos a continuar nos aparezca, si estas en conversaciones con un banco si o no
y nos muestre el select de busqueda de bancos.

- Si es que si que se me muestre lo de búsqueda como un select con varios bancos que se añaden en el select.
- Si es NO que se muestre solo si quieres que una empresa de confianza nos ayude a mostrar la mejor hipoteca.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!-- Mostrar contenido al pusal boton continuar-->
<script languague
="javascript">                                              
function mostrar
()
{
document.getElementById
('mostrar1').style.display 
= 'block';  
                                                    }                                                               function ocultar
()
{                                                                               
document
.
getElementById
('mostrar1')
.
style.display 
= 'none';                                                                           }
</script>
```

Comment: Tu problema es de javascript, elimina todo el PHP que entorpece generar una respuesta. Y creo que hay un problema en la lógica del asunto, que pasa si mi selección es `Garantía hipotecaria` que es la primera del select ??? Ahí no tengo necesidad de seleccionar algo, ya está marcado, pero el resto de cosas seguirá invisible

Comment: Si en el Select 
garantía hipotecaria es la primera opción

Comment: Creo que no me entendiste. Lo primero es que coloques un ejemplo reproducible, tu código contiene PHP que no es relevante para el problema, el cual tiene que ver solo con HTML y JS, por eso debes editar tu pregunta y corregir ese tema. Yo debo poder copiar y pegar tu código sin tener que preocuparme por esos detalle. Mas información en [MRE]

Comment: Y por otro lado, con el fondo de tu pregunta tengo dudas. Si yo soy el usuario, abro el popup y veo `Garantía hipotecaria` y justamente esa es mi selección, entonces no hago nada, pero si no hago nada no se ven el resto de las entrada, entiendes?